# PyQt5 - python-3.2 : no module available + pyuic5 cannot find PyQt5.uic module

Tags: ubuntu, installation, debian, python, pyqt

Trying to install PyQt5, the ''make install'' command ended by issuing a warning related to pyuic5 file format (see bellow)

the python path is set as

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/PyQt5
```

When testing I face these issues

## modules not found

```
help('modules')
```

doesn't display any PyQt5 module

## Conversion error

Trying to convert a .ui file to a python module

```
$  pyuic5 mywindow.ui -o mywindow_ui.py
```

results in

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named PyQt5.uic
```

Can't convert UI nor embedded QT resources anymore (pyrcc5 fails as pyuic5)

### Build

the build seems succesfull as the **/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages** directory content is

```
/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/PyQt5$ ls
__init__.py               QtNetwork.so       QtSql.so
_QOpenGLFunctions_2_0.so  QtOpenGL.so        QtSvg.so
QtBluetooth.so            QtPositioning.so   QtTest.so
QtCore.so                 QtPrintSupport.so  QtWebKit.so
QtDBus.so                 QtQml.so           QtWebKitWidgets.so
QtDesigner.so             QtQuick.so         QtWebSockets.so
QtGui.so                  QtQuickWidgets.so  QtWidgets.so
QtHelp.so                 QtSensors.so       QtX11Extras.so
QtMultimedia.so           QtSerialPort.so    QtXmlPatterns.so
QtMultimediaWidgets.so    Qt.so              uic
```

### Building environment

- debian 7.5 (wheezy)
- python3.2 standard package
- SIP 4.16.1 from sources
- Qt5.3 located at ~/Qt/5.3/gcc_64
- PyQt5 from sources

### Build sequence

In the extracted PyQt5 source directory

```
$ python3 configure.py --qmake /home/jeby6372/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

### make install log

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jeby6372/pack/PyQt-gpl-5.3/pyrcc'
install -m 755 -p "pyrcc5" "/usr/bin/pyrcc5"
strip "/usr/bin/pyrcc5"
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jeby6372/pack/PyQt-gpl-5.3/pyrcc'
install -m 644 -p /home/jeby6372/pack/PyQt-gpl-5.3/__init__.py /usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/PyQt5/
cp -f -R /home/jeby6372/pack/PyQt-gpl-5.3/pyuic/uic /usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/PyQt5/
install -m 755 -p /home/jeby6372/pack/PyQt-gpl-5.3/pyuic5 /usr/bin/
strip /usr/bin/pyuic5
strip:/usr/bin/pyuic5: File format not recognized
make: [install_pyuic5] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Any idea to solve that ?

Comment: PyQt5 definitely doesn't work with python-3.2. I've found out that the windows installation requires python-3.4.0. Installing python-3.4.1 from sources and adding /path/to/python3.4.1/lib/python3.4/site-packages to the python path on linux solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> make: [install_pyuic5] Error 1 (ignored)

Just ignore it. Your installation is fine. Open Terminal:

```
$python
>>> import PyQt5.Qt
```

if there is no error show up, you are done.